# ASP.Net MVC or Web Forms?

Tags: web-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why would you use MVC over Web Forms?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20684/why-would-you-use-mvc-over-web-forms)

What is the difference between ASP.Net MVC and Web Forms? Is either preferable? I want to use ASP.Net development as a springboard to teach myself C#. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: I recommend you use `.NET` as a springboard to teach yourself C# and avoid ASP.

Comment: @Raynos: How does your comment apply to Andrew's question? He never mentioned ASP.

Comment: @JimG. when I said ASP I meant ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET MVC. I'm basically saying stick to .NET

Comment: @Raynos: So you're saying avoid web development entirely?

Comment: @JimG. not really, you can do web development with the .NET APIs directly (like [`IHTTPAsyncHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpasynchandler.aspx)) or use framework that's closer to the metal like [Nancy](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy). Basically if you want to learn something, do it from the ground up don't start in huge abstractions. You'll waste far too much time figuring out what ASP.NET is trying to do and far too little time spend on learning C# and .NET

Comment: @Raynos: Wow. OK. Glad I asked. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

They are two different approaches to creating a web application. Web forms mirror how desktop application are created in visual studio, each page is its own self contained unit. In MVC pages are divided up into models views and controllers, controllers handle signals/events and tell models/views what to do, models handle the data, and the view is the display. each part of the MVC architecture can communicate with the others, and they are designed to be inter changeable so controller A and controller B could both work just fine with Model A.

Right now both are well supported and in common use, MVC is newer to .Net though so webforms is still more common in the industry, but both are good ways to learn. they are completely different though and it is non trivial to switch a project between the two.